# How to write regular expression in the following case using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
var value = "ID=advIcon1&CLASS=advIcon&PAGE=43&TOP=2%&LEFT=15%&WIDTH=20%&HEIGHT=10%&RSC=http://www.canon.com.hk/40th/index.html?source=seriesbanner&ICON=http://203.80.1.28/FlippingBook/Dev/Frontend/source/adv/tc_bn_314.jpg&ALT=Cannon Adv"
```

What I would like to achieve is from

```
&RSC=http://www.canon.com.hk/40th/index.html?source=seriesbanner
```

to

```
&RSC=http://www.canon.com.hk/40th/index.html?source#seriesbanner
```

which replace all the "=" between `&RSC` and `&ICON`

```
value = value.replace (/&RSC=%[=]+%&ICON/,/&RSC=%[#]+%&ICON/);
```

The above is the code I tried, not working though, how to fix the problem ? thanks

Comment: You can pull the original string apart with `.split('&')`, loop through the resulting array and pull each element apart with `split('=')`, and use the resulting 2-element array as a key|value pair to set properties on a plain js object. This is the classic way to parse out a query string. I don't quite follows the question well enough to know what you want to do then, but that should get you started.

Comment: yes the problem is when I split('=') the computer will also split the '=' in my URL which is not expected, so I need to temporary change it as another symobol

Comment: ... or you could just use `string.substring` to isolate the part of the string you want to operate on (which seems far more straightforward).

Comment: There's no generalised solution to resolving the difference between a first level `&` and a second level embedded `&`, *except* to ensure that the individual query string components are encoded before joining with `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
var value = "ID=advIcon1&CLASS=advIcon&PAGE=43&TO...";
var startIndex = value.indexOf("&RSC");
var endIndex = value.indexOf("&ICON");
var head = value.substring(0, startIndex);
var tail = value.substring(endIndex);
var body = value.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
var result = head + body.replace(/=/g, '#') + tail;
```

I don't see any advantage in trying to do the whole thing with one crazy regex.

That will only make your code harder to read and less efficient.

Better yet, make it a function you can re-use:

```
// Replaces every occurrence of replaceThis with withThis in input between
// startPattern and endPattern.

function replaceCharactersBetween(input, startPattern, endPattern, replaceThis, withThis) {
    var startIndex = input.indexOf("startPattern");
    var endIndex = input.indexOf("endPattern");
    var head = input.substring(0, startIndex);
    var tail = input.substring(endIndex);
    var body = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
    var regex = new RegExp(replaceThis, 'g');
    return head + body.replace(regex, withThis) + tail;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
value = value.replace(/RSC=([^=]+)=([^=]+)/, 'RSC=$1#$2');
```

You should look at `endoceURIComponent()` as well.

Comment: The OP wants to replace _ALL_ `=` characters between the two tokens and _NONE_ of the `=` characters after the pattern `&ICON`.  That regex will only replace one `=` character and it would replace it **EVEN IF** it occurred after `&ICON`.